# Do L'Hopital in Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I already know how to solve
$$\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1-e^{iRe^{it}}}{Re^{it}}\;dt=\int_0^{\pi} \lim_{R\to \infty}\frac{1-e^{iRe^{it}}}{Re^{it}}\;dt\tag{1}$$ use bounding, that is, the value of $\left |\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1-e^{iRe^{it}}}{Re^{it}}\;dt\right |\to 0$ as $R\to \infty$.

Is it allowed to do L'Hopital on (1) ?
I am talking about something like
$$\int_0^{\pi} \lim_{R\to \infty}\frac{1-e^{iRe^{it}}}{Re^{it}} \;dt= \int_0^{\pi}\lim_{R\to \infty} \frac{-ie^{it} \cdot e^{iRe^{it}} }{e^{it}}\;dt\quad \tag{2}$$

Comment: Yes. You can apply L'Hopital's Rule as long as the denominator tends to $\infty$ in absolute value and the differentiated ratio has  a limit. In this case, $|e^{iRe^{it}}| \to 0$ for every $t \in (0,\pi)$.

Comment: I want to clarify: do you mean "can apply L'Hopita's Rule as long as the 'numerator and denominator' tend to $\infty$ in absolute value and the differentiated ratio has a limit"?

Comment: No, L'Hopital's Rule is valid if the denominator tends to $\infty$. Numerator need not.

Comment: If the numerator tends to some constant and the denominator tends to $\infty$, then the limit value is $0$ and is solved without using L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: Yes, that is special case. But there are situations when you do not know what happens to the numerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Crux of the Question is not LH Rule. The Crux is whether we can move limit inside Integral.
If we can move the limit inside , then we can compute the limit in which-ever way we want.
If the inside is $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ , we can , of course , use LH Rule freely.

There are certain necessary & sufficient conditions to whether the limit can be moved inside the Integral.
The given Case seems to satisfy the Criteria. It is also $\infty/\infty$ with a limiting value.
Hence we can move the limit inside the integral & then use LH Rule freely.

Here is the latest work on that theory :

https://journalofinequalitiesandapplications.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13660-020-02502-w

"Interchanging a limit and an integral: necessary and sufficient conditions
Takashi Kamihigashi
Journal of Inequalities and Applications volume 2020, Article number: 243"

ADDENDUM :

In Case we can move the limit inside the integral & the inside term is $c_1/\infty$ , we can not use LH Rule.
If we still proceed to take Derivatives with LH Rule , we might unluckily get wrong values like $0/c_2$ , $c_3/1$ , $\infty/\infty$ , $\infty/c_4$ , $\infty/0$ inside the integral , which will make the over-all computation invalid/wrong.

Comment: Woa.. I didn't notice the interchange limit and integral have principal. Thank you!